# How can i swap the contents of a vector no matter how long its length is?

Tags: matlab

A vector is filled with numbers

`v = [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 ,.....]` .

**case 1**

How do i swap the numbers in such a way that even numbers will swap with its corresponding odd number ending up as such,

`v = [ 2 , 1 , 4 , 3 , 6 , 5 , 8 , 7 , 10 , 9 , 12 , 11 , ....]`

**case 2**

Additionally, is it also possible to swap only the corresponding odd numbers to attain results in this way?

`v = [ 3 , 2 , 1 , 4 , 7 , 6 , 5 , 8 , 11 , 10 , 9 , 12 ,.... ]`

**case 3**

same with the 2nd case but instead of swapping the odd numbers ill need to swap the even numbers instead displaying a result that will end like this.

`v = [ 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 5 , 8 , 7 , 6 , 9 , 12 , 11 , 10 .....]`

The vector V length might change from time to time with the stored numbers being single digit integers. 
any possible help given is and will be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time and any input given!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is case 1:

```
m = 1:10

n = zeros(10,1);

n(1:2:end) = m(2:2:end);
n(2:2:end) = m(1:2:end)
```

cases 2 and 3 are trivial from there

Comment: Hi @Dan. Ive tried to solve case 2 and 3 but i cant seem to get it. Could really use your help here. 
When i tried doing it i keep getting an error message saying `"In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of
elements in B and I must be the same."`